# JPQL query not including entities if no children even though a left join fetch is specified

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Using Spring 4.1.4, Spring Data 1.7.1, Hibernate 4.3.8

I'm trying to get a left join fetch to work in a JPQL for performance reasons, but in cases where SubItem1 has 0 entries I don't get back my entity.

My JPQL looks like this:

`@Query("select distinct foo from Foo foo
join fetch foo.parentItem pi 
left join fetch pi.ZeroOrMoreChildren zChild 
join fetch zChild.parentOfZChild pofz 
join fetch pofz.grantParentOfZChild where foo.someFeild = ?1")`

The problem I have is that is there are 0 zChild entries then I don't get back a foo object. My objects are all hydrated correctly, but obviously I'm missing entities that should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the problem is that you need left joins all the way down.

So the query should have looked like this.

`@Query("select distinct foo from Foo foo
join fetch foo.parentItem pi 
left join fetch pi.ZeroOrMoreChildren zChild 
left join fetch zChild.parentOfZChild pofz 
left join fetch pofz.grantParentOfZChild where foo.someFeild = ?1")`